# JavaScript, loop over each key and sum the count

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to Sum of the key ‘total’ from the following object, but unable to find the way. I have tried to find it by using `Object.key`

```
const data = {
  "item1": {},
  "item2": {
      "total": 13,
  },
   "item3": {},
  "item4": {
      "total": 12,
  }
}
const count = Object.keys(data).map(item => data[item].total);
console.log(count);
```

This is what I have tried and in consol.log it is printing 13 and 12 but I am not able to do Sum of them. Also, I have tried the reduce method which is suggested in some of the following answers.

Comment: Show us what you tried that didn't work. The purpose of this site is to help fix your code , not to be a free code writing service

Comment: hey @charlietfl I have updated the question and also have added the exact response which I m receiving from API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

> The `Object.values()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

and [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

> The `reduce()` method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each member of the array resulting in a single output value.

```js
const data = {
  "item1": {},
  "item2": {
      "total": 13,
  },
   "item3": {},
  "item4": {
      "total": 12,
  }
}

var sum = Object.values(data)
                .filter(value => Object.keys(value).length !== 0)
                .reduce((a,c) => a+c.total, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: always provide a starting value for reduce!

Comment: This happens to work because the object has exactly 2 values. If it has more, then this method will return `NaN`. If it has less, the returned value will just be the only value in the object.

Comment: yes it is returning NaN when there are more than 2 values

Comment: @MAR, I have updated the answer with two more objects and it is returning the correct result....

Comment: @Mamun sometimes I can't rec the 'total' key in some objects.

Comment: @MAR, in that case you can filter out the empty objects.......updated the answer....please check.....thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use `Object.keys()` to loop over the keys of the object and then access the `total` property of each object:

```js
var data = {
  "item1": {
    "total": 17
  },
  "item2": {
    "total": 13
  },
  "item3": {}
};

var sum = 0;
Object.keys(data).forEach(key => sum += data[key].total || 0);
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: if there are more than 2 values then it is returning NaN.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get all the values in your data.
Then use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to calculate the total.

```js
const data = {
  "item1": { "total": 17 },
  "item2": { "total": 13 }
}

const values = Object.values(data);
console.log("Values:", values);

const total = values.reduce((a, c) => a + c.total, 0);
console.log("Total:", total);
```

---

Of course, you don't need the intermediate variable:

```
const total = Object.values(data).reduce((a, c) => a + c.total, 0);
```

Comment: I'd rather call `sum` the first argument of `reduce` callback to make it more understandable

Comment: @fanjabi: it's common practice to name the callback's parameters: `accumulator` and `currentValue`. That's where I got the `a, c` from.

Comment: ok then call then `accumulator` and `currentValue` beucase `(a,c)` looks like `(a,b)` to me

Comment: I'd rather add a few validity checks in case of N/A values.

Comment: @Kaiido: I think that's beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score -1):

```
 const sum = Object.keys(yourObject).map(key => yourObject[key].total).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: It looks as a perfectly right answer. The requester is welcome to ask for more information is needed.